# manipulate arrays inside numpy ndarrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How do i manipulate arrays inside a numpy ndarray in python?

For example if i got an array like this

```
a1 = np.array([1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3])
>>
[[1 1 1 1]
 [2 2 2 2]
 [3 3 3 3]]
```

and i want to exchange one or multiple rows inside the array.

For example i want to insert the array `[0,0,0,0]` at the first index, so it looks like this:

```
[[0 0 0 0]
 [2 2 2 2]
 [3 3 3 3]]
```

or if i got a second array like this

```
a2 = np.array([1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8])
>>
[[1 2 3 4]
 [5 6 7 8]]
```

and i want it to replace the first two rows of my first array like this:

```
[[1 2 3 4]
 [5 6 7 8]
 [3 3 3 3]]
```

How do i do these operations if speed is a big factor?

Comment: Why do i get so much minus to this question??

Comment: Mainly because you ask a really basic operation, and don't focus enough on the "speed is a big factor". You should show us your attempt to solve this using several strategies (or at least one), and ask us about which one would be the best one !

Comment: ok i get it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite straitghforward:

```
t = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3]])
t[0, :] = np.zeros(t.shape[1])
```

Simply have to access the first row using `t[0, :]`. I use here `np.zeros` because I'm pretty sure it's the fastest way to initialize zero vector.

The second case is based on the same logic.

```
t = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3, 3]])
t2 = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]])
t[0:2, :] = t2
```

Actually, `t[0, :]` means first row, all element in the column, and can be shortened as `t[0]`. `t[0:2]` means all rows from index 0 to index 2 (not included).

And about speed...

```
$ timeit t[0:2] = t2
805 ns ± 2.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

No need to overcomplicate this thing ;)